# CSS to change background color of ASP.NET server controls

Tags: html, css

I have a Div with a table (2x2) inside it. I also have a CSS file but I am not following how to change the background color of table columns where ASP.NET DropDown exists. I tried:

**Edited**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ddl1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Stylesheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl2" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS I attempted:

```
body
{
}
table
{
    border-color:Olive;
    border-style:solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table td
{
    width:200px;
}

table.DropDownList
{
    width:200px;
    background-color:Gray;
}
```

Comment: is the class name of this DropDown element also named DropDown? Post a simple version of the table code.

Comment: No, I just tried DropDown to cover all DropDowns as I used table. No class name.

Comment: We're working blind here - need to see your HTML.

Comment: Just adding buddy. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: That's not the output, that's your server-side code.

Comment: The output is just showing a border with two DropDownLists in it. I finding it difficult to upload image at this point of time.

Comment: You have no class attributes named `DropDownList`. How exactly were you expecting `table.DropDownList` to do *anything*?

Comment: Agreed. What changes you suggest.

Comment: @Diodeus provided an answer below that is correct and really the only "good" way to do what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess without full HTML:

```
#form1 td {
    background-color:Gray
}
```

**EDIT:**

But this will colour all of your cells, even those not containing SELECT.

You need to use JavaScript. jQuery makes this quite easy:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#form1 select').parent().css('background-color','Gray')
}
```

Comment: But td will cover all other columns. I only want to change color of columns where ASP DropDownList is contained.

Comment: You can't do that without using JavaScript. CSS cannot do this.

Comment: 'select' changes the color of the control and not of the table cell.

Comment: @RPK - That's why he's got the `.parent()` in there. It gets the parent of the select.

Answer (score 0):

does it work within the tags without css?

```
<asp:DropDownList backcolor="gray" ID="ddl1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

**edit**

also, since it probably gets rendered into html you might want to change the style of the select box?..

```
select {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

..you could use the within functionality, but only for the select-boxes again - so not exactly what you wanted, without further logic I think you could only go for css-classes or ids (used at the td's):

```
td select {
   background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: Let me clear. I want to change the background color of the cell and not the control itself.

Comment: if you are interested in css and the possibilities of its selecting syntax look at http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

Comment: td select changes the background of the control and not the column cell.